# Underscore.js equivalent of jQuery's $.inArray()?

Tags: jquery, underscore.js

Does underscore.js have an equivalent of the jQuery function `$.inArray`? I am trying to find duplicates in an object and return only unique values back. I have done this in jQuery but would like to use underscore JS.

```
var result = [];
$.each(formValuesObj.fields.list, function (i, e) {
    if ($.inArray(e, result) == -1) 
        result.push(e);
});

formValuesObj.fields.list = result;

$.each(formValuesObject, function () {
    if (this.fieldSelectId == formValues3.fieldSelectId) {
        contains = true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need underscore for this, plain ol' javascript has you covered!

```
result.indexOf('value') == -1
```

Answer (score 2):

Underscore does this in one function:

```
var uniqueValuesArray = _.uniq(duplicatedValuesArray);
```

> **uniq** _.uniq(array, [isSorted], [iteratee]) *Alias: **unique***
>
> Produces a duplicate-free version of the array, using === to test object equality. In particular only the first occurence of each value is kept. If you know in advance that the array is sorted, passing true for isSorted will run a much faster algorithm. If you want to compute unique items based on a transformation, pass an iteratee function.

http://underscorejs.org/#uniq

Comment: Thanks, i looked around in there but i guess i missed it.

Comment: Any idea why i can't assign the result to a variable ?

var result = _.uniq(formValuesObj.fields.list);

result 
> undefined

Comment: Ah. It may work in-place. So the array you pass into the function is the one that gets updated. Not very clear from the documentation.

Comment: I checked that but the array i passed it doesn't get updated it still has all the duplicate values.

Comment: Definitely works on my end the way I wrote in the answer: https://jsfiddle.net/q8ueufLj/1/ (check the console). What's an example of  what `formValuesObj.fields.list` contains?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` and `indexOf` in `underscore.js`.

E.g.

```
var arr= [];
var result= [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9, 8, 9];

var notDuplicatedOnes = _.filter(result, function(num) {
    if (arr.indexOf(num) == -1) {
       arr.push(num);
       return num;
    }
});
// Returns [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Iwant to return non duplicate values

Eg: arr= [1,1,1,3,3,3,7,7,7]
result = [1,3,7]

Comment: @Ratan I already gave you the food, now I should chew it for you. Check my updated answer.

Comment: sorry my friend i am new to programming takes me time to understand new things :(

Comment: @RatanServegar Oh, it's okay then. But i'd suggest to go with DoXick answer. It's much simpler to use pure javascript code.